# How to convert Combining Diacritical Marks to single grapheme

Tags: html, unicode

I have a PDF document with text I want to copy and paste into an HTML document.

The problem is that all accented characters are actually made of [combining diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) instead of [single Unicode code points](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html).

So for instance, `é` which would be represented by Unicode point `&#xE9;` is here encoded as two seperate chars like `&#x65;&#x301;` (`e` & `́`).

This isn't very easy to deal with, especially since some browsers (Firefox) display a whitespace after the accented letter whereas some others (Chrome) do not.

Hence, is there a way to automatically convert those pesky characters into friendly single Unicode code point characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to [normalize](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) the string to one of the composed form, NFC or NFKC (The difference is that NFKC removes some formatting distinctions like ligatures).

I'm not sure what you mean exactly by 'automatically' but I believe it is possible with most languages, for example :

- Python : [unicodedata.normalize()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize):

  ```
  import unicodedata
  original_string = '\u0065\u0301'
  normalized_string = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', original_string)
  ```
- Java / Android : [Normalizer.normalize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html#normalize(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.text.Normalizer.Form))

  ```
  String normalizedText = Normalizer.normalize(originalString, Normalizer.Form.NFC)
  ```
- .Net : [String.Normalize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1(v=vs.110).aspx)

  ```
  string normalizedText = originalString.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
  ```
- Oracle SQL [COMPOSE()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions025.htm)

  ```
  SELECT COMPOSE(UNISTR('\0065\0301')) FROM DUAL;
  ```

Online test : [Dencode](https://dencode.com/en/string/unicode-normalization) (NFD and NFKD are called *Decoded NFC*, *Decoded NFKC* )

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, you can use [uconv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) to convert from one Unicode form to the other.

To convert a text file from UTF-8 NFD to UTF-8 NFC :

```
uconv -f utf8 -t utf8 -x NFC $in_file -o $out_file
```

Since you mentioned copy/pasting, you could also do it directly with an alias. Assuming your Linux is using UTF-8 by default :

```
alias to_nfc='xclip -o -selection clipboard | uconv -f - -x NFC | xclip -selection clipboard'
```

Then you only have to type `to_nfc` in a terminal to have your clipboard converted.

On Debian-based systems (Ubuntu, etc.), uconv is in package `icu-devtools` :

```
sudo apt install icu-devtools
```

On Centos: `yum install icu`

On Mac (or Windows if you have Perl installed) you could try

```
perl -C -MUnicode::Normalize -pe '$_=NFC($_)' < $in_file > $out_file
```